# Matrix equation with Mathematica

Tags: matrix, wolfram-mathematica, matrix-multiplication, equation, linear-equation

I'm trying to solve the equation `H1 = S.H2-H2.S` where `H1` and `H2` are known 10x10 matrices depending on two parameters `J1,J2` meanwhile `S` has to be determined.

In my try, I do

1. Define matrices

   ```
    H1 = J1/2*{{-1/2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    {1, -1/2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, -1/2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 1, -1/2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 1, 1, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, -1, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}};
   ```

and

```
H2 = J2/2*{{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
{0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1},
{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 1, 1},
{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0},
{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0},
{0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0},
{0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, -1}};
```

2. Define S matrix as `S = Array[X, {10, 10}];`
3. Solve it: `Solve[S.H1 - H1.S == H2, Flatten[S]]`

The final result is an empty array `{}` which doesn't depend on `J1,J2`.

**My question is: does it mean that the matrix `S` is an empty array because there is no solution or am I doing something wrong? Because I was expecting something depending on the parameters `J1,J2`.**

I'd appreciate a lot comments on my issue!

Thanks :-)

Comment: Try `Reduce[S.H1-H1.S==H2,Flatten[S]]//Simplify`